# How to make a RAID disk light blink (on Linux)?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, hard-drive

I have a RAID10 hot-swap disk that is about to fail (according to `smartctl -a /dev/sdc`. The disk is mounted in a rack 4U server).

Unfortunately, the disks are not marked, so I'd like to get the disk light to blink.

I tried the following commands:

```
dd if=/dev/sdc1 of=/dev/null bs=16
ledctl locate_off=/dev/sdc
```

which didn't turn any lights on on any disk.

Any other ideas how can I identify which of the RAID disks is the soon-to-fail disk?

### Edit:

The RAID is a Linux software raid (`mdadm`).

Comment: What kind of controller/server/etc?  I suspect this would be something covered by the dell/hpe tools, or something for a given controller.

Comment: @zoredache seems right on the mark here:  the tools for blinking LEDs are different but present on all major HBA vendors. I just confirmed with LSI and PERC, and I've used the AHA HBA's blink function a number of times.

No matter which controller you're using, there should be a blink/identify function.

Comment: The RAID is a Linux software raid (mdadm). @Zoredache

Comment: Wow, almost a year later?  Is this still the same failed array?  Still don't know don't think there is any generic way to blink lights.

Comment: `ledctl locate=/dev/sdd` to start.. `ledctl off={/dev/sdd}` to stop.. this lives in the *ledmon* package.

Comment: @ethrbunny why not put it as a full-fleged answer, so it can get upvotes?

Answer (score 7):

To start: `ledctl locate=/dev/sdd`
To stop: `ledctl off={/dev/sdd}`

This lives in the **ledmon** package.

Comment: This only works on some systems and/or disks. The simple solution with `dd` should be much more reliable.

Comment: I believe it should be `ledctl locate_off` instead of `ledctl off`. According to `man ledctl`: "`locate_off` Turns only Locate LED off; `off` Turns only Status LED and Failure LED off". I can confirm that `ledctl locate_off` works on my Ubuntu 18.04 servers. Have not tried `ledctl off`.

Comment: These commands work on centos

Comment: @EM0 If you have a different answer then submit it as such. Please don't edit existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just simple looop for blinking a disk

while :; do smartctl -a /dev/sdaX; done; #simple looop for blinking a disk

Comment: Genius! And don't worry, `CTRL+C` breaks the loop just fine. Might also want to through `1>/dev/null` in there too.

Comment: What's `1>/dev/null` do? What should the full command be?

Answer (score 0):

To start: `ledctl locate=/dev/sdX`
To stop: `ledctl locate_off=/dev/sdX`

`ledctl` is installed by the **ledmon** package.

(Copied from ethrbunny's answer, but changed to use `locate_off` instead of `off`, which "Turns only Status LED and Failure LED off." according to `man ledctl`.)